# Character code different between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, character-encoding

I have a string handling function in C++ as well as in C#. In C++ the code for the character `ˆ` is returned as `-120` where as in C# it is `710`. While building in C++ using visual studio 2010 I have set the character set as "Not set" in the project settings. In C# I am using `System.Text.Encoding.Default` during one of the conversions. Does that make any difference? How can I get same behavior in C++ as well as in C#?

Comment: What datatype are you using to store the character in your C++ code?

Comment: Could you post the code you’re using to get that value? The code of the caret sign should be 94.

Comment: 710 is a decimal representation of the Unicode codepoint named "MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT", which seems to look similar to the `^`.  My question is why he is seeing '-120' as a code point.  If he's seeing a negative number, he might be using the wrong (signed, and possibly too narrow) data type.

Comment: I was using `int` as the datatype in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character is U+02C6. The encoding you're using in C++ is probably CP 1252 which encodes this character as the byte 0x88 (which is -120 when showing a signed char in decimal) . C# uses the encoding UTF-16, which encodes this character as 0x02C6 (710 in decimal).

You can use UTF-16 in C++ on Windows by using wchar_t insead of char.

You can't make C# strings use CP1252, but you can get byte arrays in different encodings from a String using Encodings.

```
byte[] in_cp1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("Your string here");
```